# Door are not showed properly after upload visio document

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I uploaded visio with proper placement of door using microsoft, uploaded the same file in draw.io but didnt get proper result. Can you please suggest what I am doing wring?

Please find attachments[image] [image]

please find link to original document:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UP71eAbE-mEiw9Z8KhYPJeryBf5pBxHt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: did you import.vsdx to diagrams.net online or desktop app? What steps exactly did you perform, please? Regards,

Comment: Thanks Marija for response. I didn't follow more steps just upload VSDX file online
1. imported vsdx in diagrams.net online

Comment: Thanks Yes, you are right, some parts aren't imported well. Could you please post this issue here: https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues and track its progress. As a workaround you could use door shape from our library when you import file (just type "door" into Search field.

Comment: Hi Marija,
Thanks for the workaround. I reported in issues.

Comment: Hi Marija,
Can you please help me out in saving visio document to html using API? I want to export to html immediatly after uploading document, so i was thinking like there will be API used to convert by sending vsdx file as post parameter to API and it will return html content link in return.
Thanks alot in advance.